# Is it Possible to Create Custom SharePoint Explorer?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to Create Explorer that can explore the SharePoint Libraries same as Window Explorer.
I Don't want to use Default SharePoint Explorer Provided by SharePoint

Is it Possible ?

Comment: What are your requirements? If you're after a basic hierarchical view of the site with rudimentary browsing and copying capabilities, Manage Content And Structure (available in SharePoint Server) provides this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shihan has mentioned the right thing. The best way is to develop a custom web part that will act as a SharePoint Explorer.

If you want a pre-build utility that acts as a SharePoint Explorer, then here it is the SharePoint Explorer 2007: http://spm.codeplex.com/

This utility is currently available only for SP 2003 and 2007, soon they are going to release for 2010 edition.

The other paid utility is here: http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5821

Comment: SharePoint Manager is an object model explorer, you can't really do much with the content, it's intended for administrators and developers to inspect the system under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible to develop a WebPart that behaves more or less like Windows Explorer. Our company is building a DocumentExplorer that looks and behaves (with drag & drop support) like windows explorer, a WebPart that can replace the default XslListView-WebPart.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Outlook you can also connect up SharePoint libraries which will then give you an explorer like view inside Outlook. Simply click on the Connect to Outlook button in the ribbon when in a library